# Error hiding datagridview columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datagridview

I have the following gridview, the problem is that when I hide some columns so that they are not displayed when doing a search, when doing so I load the gridview with the hidden columns and then it makes me another gridview with all the columns that I have in the database data.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview"  runat="server" Height="202px" style="background-color: #FFFFFF" Width="413px" AutoGenerateColumns="true" 
        AllowPaging="true" DataKeyNames="Id, email, phone" PageSize="5">

          <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB" HeaderText="Subaddress" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DPT" HeaderText="Department" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Level" HeaderText="Level" />
    </columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting AutoGenerateColumns="false".

Comment: Thank you very much was that

Comment: Great!  Thank you!